# plotlyでグラフのサイズを自動にしたい。

Tags: python, plotly-python

plotlyで、一回グラフのサイズを指定してグラフを作り、、そのあとに、自動でグラフのサイズを成形したいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか？
目的としては、サイズを指定したグラフとサイズが自動で変わるグラフを作り、htmlで保存して、サイズを指定した方は、印刷用。サイズが自動で変わる方は、使うモニターの解像度に合わせて適切なサイズを表示させる用途で使いたいのです。

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-4,4])
fig.update_layout(
    width=1000,
    height=1000 * 2 ** 0.5,
)              
fig.show()
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True
) 
fig.show()
```

htmlを生成する場合、

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-4,4])
fig.update_layout(
    width=1000,
    height=1000 * 2 ** 0.5,
)              
fig.write_html("a.html")
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True
) 
fig.write_html("aa.html")
```

異なるサイズのグラフを表示させたい（片方は、サイズが自動で変わるようにしたいです）

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3129322/9014308)

Comment: 本来、plotlyでグラフのサイズを指定せずに、htmlに保存をした場合、自動でサイズが変更されます。

Comment: 例えばWindows10のPython3.9.5でコマンドプロンプトからファイル化したスクリプトを実行すると、デフォルトのブラウザにタブが2つ表示されるようですが、スクリプトは終了してしまうので2つ目は中身が表示されないようです。Pythonインタプリタにスクリプトを入力すると、プロセスは終了しないので2つ目のタブも表示されたままになります。いずれもブラウザの状態(全画面表示中か画面の1部にサイズ指定しているか)に応じたサイズに表示されます。どんな環境で実行していてどんな結果になっているのか、それの何が問題でどうなって欲しいのかといったことを詳細化して追記してみてください。今の質問記事だと読み取れない感じです。

Comment: htmlで生成した場合、どの環境と言うのは関係するとは思えませんが、jupyter notebookで実行し、chromeで確認しています。htmlはマルチプラットフォームですので、重要性はないと考えています。

Comment: 例えば「サイズが自動で変わるようにしたい」というのが何のサイズなのか、それがどこに表示されるのか、自動で変わるというのはどういうことなのか、についての説明が記述されていないでしょう。

Comment: htmlを保存する時に、サイズ指定をしなければ、自動でサイズが変更されます。逆に言えば、通常、サイズ指定せずに、htmlに保存するはずなので、それを説明する方が難しいです。いうならば、レスポンシブルデザインに対応したhtmlにしたいというのが正確ですが…

Comment: Jupyter notebookを使っていると、処理結果がjupyter画面内の出力セル部分に表示されるので、それをもってサイズが変わらないと誤解しているのでは？

Comment: 実行してから、解答して頂いても宜しいでしょうか？実行せずに、推測だけで言われても、話は進みません。こちらは、実行して動いていないので、質問しています。

Comment: 先ほどのは一応WindowsのAnacondaでいれたJupyter notebookで実行してから書いてますよ。その動いていないという部分をスクリーンショットで掲載してみてはどうでしょう？あるいは単に貴方の環境の各モジュールを最新版にしていないだけかもしれませんね。

Comment: 二度目の `fig.update_layout` を `fig.update_layout(width=None, height=None, autosize=True)` に変更するとよいかもしれません。

Comment: @metropolis さんありがとうございます。お陰様で解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

何かヒントというか何が問題なのかが分かってきたかもしれません。
2つ目で`autosize=True`を指定しても、その前に指定した`width=1000,height=1000 * 2 ** 0.5,`は残ったままなので、それが影響しているのかもしれませんね。
最初の固定サイズの指定を消すか相対値化する機能があるか探してみては？ 無ければ2つ目は最初から作り直すとか？

とりあえず以下のように2つ目を最初から作り直すようにすると、出来ると思われます。

```
# plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-4,4])
fig.update_layout(
    width=1000,
    height=1000 * 2 ** 0.5,
)              
fig.show()
#### 2つ目グラフもあらためて最初から作成する
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-4,4]) ####
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True
) 
fig.show()
```

---

@metropolis さんコメントの方法も同様の結果で有効と思われます。

```
fig.update_layout(
    width=None,
    height=None,
    autosize=True
)
```